# Powershell add code after specific character in a string

Tags: powershell, character, addition

I am writing a script to get some windows report and send it via mail [http]. 
The problem is that when I send the mail it does not respect the new lines from the variable, so I want to add a 
 tag after every . [dot]. It will solve my problem.

For example this:

```
@{Message=SureBackup job 'example' finished with Warning.
Job details: [example]: Cannot detect IP address. 
Ping test will be skipped}
```

If I put it in a variable it will respect the new lines but when I send it...

```
@{Message=SureBackup job 'example' finished with Warning. Job details: [example]: Cannot detect IP address. Ping test will be skipped}
```

It is the result.

I do not have any idea about how to replace it with:

```
@{Message=SureBackup job 'example' finished with Warning.<br>
Job details: [example]: Cannot detect IP address.<br> 
Ping test will be skipped}<br>
```

It will solve all our problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using:

```
$info -replace "[.]",".<br>"
```